# Signing in to a website using discord Oauth (only using python requests, no selenium)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying very hard to login to a website which uses Discord Oauth. To do this I have to make a request to

```
https://discord.com/api/v9/oauth2/authorize?client_id=896549597550358548&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.monkeebot.xyz/oauth/discord&scope=identify guilds
```

However. Discord returns a an errored response:

```
<Response [200]>
{'location': 'https://www.monkeebot.xyz/oauth/discord?error=access_denied&error_description=The+resource+owner+or+authorization+server+denied+the+request'}
```

```
url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/oauth2/authorize?client_id=896549597550358548&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.monkeebot.xyz/oauth/discord&scope=identify guilds"

headers = {
    "authorization": "",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.47",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-length": "36",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "origin": "https://discord.com",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "referer": "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=896549597550358548&redirect_uri=https://www.monkeebot.xyz/oauth/discord&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.47",
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={}, allow_redirects=True)
```

Does anybody have any experience with doing this? I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I have added the correct authorization etc, and I have tried it on different websites that use Discord oauth, but I get this error every time.

Any helps/debugging tips would be very grateful.

Comment: what kind of response are expecting once the authetication is successful?

Comment: I can give you the code to generate {"location": "https://www.monkeebot.xyz/oauth/discord?code=7R5oOGKOXU5S0AWEXo2PojXegJSaYm"}. Would that be OK? This code is different evey time when you hit on authorize button

Comment: your post request in incomplete. You need to create proper post request using your credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before executing this script, please create your auth code and use it in below "Authorization" key. I don't want to share mine :)

```
import requests
import json


def generate_code():
    url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/oauth2/authorize?client_id=896549597550358548&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.monkeebot.xyz/oauth/discord&code=0nNWo24HJQgwytTMlqkwgdil9fW24k&scope=identify guilds"

    payload = json.dumps({"permissions": "0", "authorize": True})

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "USE YOUR AUTH CODE HERE. YOu need to CREATE it first",
        "X-Super-Properties": "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",
        "X-Discord-Locale": "en-US",
        "X-Debug-Options": "bugReporterEnabled",
        "Alt-Used": "discord.com",
        "Cookie": "__dcfduid=7dc5606419a411ed9b1fee90ba2eef9f; __sdcfduid=7dc5606419a411ed9b1fee90ba2eef9f20120e864cf33496bedf659a7820954f7611454b15423f7553e3e85c08756a75",
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    return response.json()


print(generate_code())
```